# What & How are Migration Projects ? Are they good for long term career growth?

Tags: career-development

I have 2 years prior experience as a Full Stack developer (Front end and back end).

I recently joined a company, and a team-lead wants to allocate me to a Migration Project. A project is to be migrated to cloud. She said that my role would be a developer role, the cloud where the migration is to happen is AWS. And I have to learn Lambda Functions and work in it. Now, the client interview has not been scheduled yet, but it will soon be.  I can say NO to the lead.

So, I want to know, if this migration project would be good for my future career growth. And how would be my work-life balance if I am selected for this project?

Comment: Asking for a specific choice or opinions is off-topic here, so I will just comment on your question. Since migration to cloud is, to say the least, quite popular these days and such a move will introduce new frameworks and technologies to you (think of azure, aws etc..) I wouldn't see it as a bad career choice. In regards to WLB: You can get hit by a ton of hours in any project/field/workplace..

Comment: @iLuvLogix `You can get hit by a ton of hours in any project/field/workplace..` - Please explain this?

Comment: What I meant is that you can encounter a scenario with poor WLB (lots of hours, all-in, less time for yourself and family/friends ) in any job..

Comment: I think learning new technology in the same field is generally good for you and your career.  I do not believe that there is anything specific regarding WLB as compared to any other large project.

Answer (score 2):

> I can say NO to the lead.

Make sure this is true, before you reject the position. In some companies repeatedly rejecting positions will find you on the way out the door. They need people to work on client projects to generate income, and to pay salaries.

> So, I want to know, if this migration project would be good for my
> future career growth.

That depends on the direction of your company. Look around are the new projects using AWS or other cloud systems. Gaining the skills in AWS may make you eligible for more projects in the next few years.  Or is this a one-off project that will not lead to future work?

> And how would be my work-life balance if I am selected for this
> project?

Cloud, AWS, migration have no impact on work-life balance. Corprate culture, client corporate culture, and staffing levels have a huge inpact on work-life balance.

> What...are Migration Projects?

That is moving from one language/platform/framework to another language/platform/framework.

These can be good projects or disasters, and everything in between. If your company underestimates the amount of work, it can be late and over budget. Both of these things are very stressful. These projects can be constantly moving targets especially if development on the old system is continuing. Testing to make sure both systems give the same answer can be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

1. Migration projects as a project category are not good or bad in and of itself. All this does is describe roughly what your task will be and this project category is neither particulary prestigious nor (necessarily) a red flag. All it does is roughly describe your task.

   Answering you whether or not this is good for your career is impossible, nor is this SE intended for this kind of advice.
2. Your work-life-balance is something you need to discuss with your employer. Again, a migration project is merely a category describing roughly your tasks. You may drown in work or you may find yourself in a fair company, where you can discuss a work schedule fitting your criteria.
3. One thing that can be said with at least some degree of certainty is that a migration project means, you won't create something new, but rather dig through code written by someone else. Your job is then to figure out how to transfer the existing functionality provided by the existing code to a new codebase on a different platform. This often bears some risks, so you may want to check some things:

   - Is the codebase well documented? Maybe you can look with your employer into the codebase to be migrated and see for yourself what the documentation looks like. While at it - check what standards are in place. Codebases to be migrated *can* look like an unmitigated disaster, so check beforehand
   - While at it - are they using Git? How did they version their code otherwise?
   - What does the review process look like?
   - Is the team whom worked on the codebase prior to migration still at the company and can they help with the migration?
   - Other than that there is the usual - what are the exact requirements, what does the schedule look like, how much personnel is available etc.

Whether or not you like this type of personal project is personal preference. Myself I do not like these projects, however this is because I have usually encountered a poorly documented spaghetti codebase, which didn't adhere to standards or best practices. Many developers prefer creating new things, rather than understanding someone else's existing code and adapting it. It is up to you to figure these things out.

Answer (score 1):

- Will learn more about AWS services so can put it on your CV
- Work-life balance should be ok as it's already developed service and typically migration is delegated to back offices which have more laid back culture
- Will deal with code written by other people so your life will depend on its quality - it can be crappy or not so. Need to evaluate does it have unit/integration tests, QA and how migration process would be organized before accepting such role.
- How long will it take and will you develop new features - such projects can be far away from a business where you won't have much impact and perceived more as cost than profit objects so you need to be cautious about staying too long